# how to split a string

Tags: c#, string

i have a string like 123Prefix1pics.zip

i want to split it into 123 Prefix1 pics.zip and store them in different variables
i m trying to do it in c#,.net
jst litle bit confused on how to use split method

Comment: You get better answers if you mention the language.

Comment: What language? Put some effort in please.

Comment: Why should anyone waste there time guessing? I might most likly be .Net but could also be Java/c/c++ etc

Comment: you should split that string by what rule?

Comment: You should give more info. Does the file name always follow the pattern of number/string/number/string/suffix?

Comment: What is your pattern for spliting these string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
splitArray = Regex.Split(subjectString, @"(?<=\p{N})(?=\p{L})");
```

will work in C# to split in positions between a number (`\p{N}`) and a letter (`\p{L}`).

If you also want to split between a letter and a number, use

```
splitArray = Regex.Split(subjectString, @"(?<=\p{L})(?=\p{N})|(?<=\p{N})(?=\p{L})");
```

however, that splits your example too much.

Comment: The answer is elegant but as Tim suggests, it doesn't produce the required result - yet it gets marked correct?

Answer (score 5):

You only want to split that one string?  Too easy!

```
string filename = "123Prefix1pics.zip"
string part1 = "123"
string part2 = "Prefix1"
string part3 = "pics.zip"
```

Ok this is a joke, but it gives the right answer.  Unless you generalise your splitting rule, or provide further examples, we can only guess.

You *may* be asking to make a string break after a numeral, but again I'm only guessing.

Comment: :) I guess we agree on this, Kirk.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with:

```
string filename = "123Prefix1pics.zip"
string part1 = filename.Substring(0, 3);
string part2 = filename.Substring(3, 7);
string part3 = filename.Substring(10, 4);
```

You can also note String.Split() needs a separator argument, like an `;` or `,`. As you don't have any separator, you can try two approaches:

- Make sure all your filenames have same format; this way, you can to use `Substring()` to break your strings
- You can identify a more general pattern, as "numbers, 7 characters plus 4 more characters" and to use a regular expression. This is a more advanced solution and can lead to maintenance problems;

I recommend you to stick with first option.

Answer (score 1):

You can split it like this:

- your ip in a string variable like this:
- create a char vector
- then a string vector

Code:

```
string theIP="this is string"; 
char[] separator={' '}; //you can put multiple separators
string[] result = theIP.Split(separator,StringSplitOptions.None);
```

this means `result[0]` is `"this"`, `result[1]` is `"is"`, and so on.

You can find a good tutorial about string splitting here:

http://goldwin-advertising.ro/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=10:splitstring&catid=3:howto&Itemid=5

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Look like you want to split by fixed size.

So use `yourString.Substring(0, 3);`